# What does it mean, "coming at all"?

Tags: meaning

After reducing her size to cellular level, Carol meets his friends:

> Carol: Well, actually, we weren't planning on **coming at all** at first,
>   but then, you know, we started getting all the emails. Plus my sister
>   was having a lump removed. She's fine, thank God, but I still needed
>   to see her.

What does it mean, "coming at all"?

I know "come at" means "attack", but context is not about attacking.

I find this line in Downsizing 2019

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of 'at all'?

Comment: I thought "coming at all" single phrase.

Comment: But do you understand it now that you’ve looked up ‘at all’, as @DecapitatedSoul suggested?